# Can't sort model by QDateTime with using QSortFilterProxyModel sort by role

Tags: c++, qt, model, qml

I am stuck with simple problem but I can't figure it out why my model is not sorted.
I have **SimpleModel** class that inherits from **QAbstractListModel** and I want to sort it by **DateTime** role.

[image: ccc]

This is how I am setting the Proxy in my `main.cpp`:

```
SimpleModel m;
ProxyModel proxyModel;
proxyModel.setSourceModel(&m);
proxyModel.setSortRole(SimpleModel::SimpleRoles::DateTimeRole);
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("simpleModel", &proxyModel);
```

My Items in the **SimpleModel** are objects from **SimpleItem** class which has only Name and DateTime. This is my SimpleModel data method:

```
QVariant SimpleModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if(!index.isValid()) {
        return QVariant();
    }

    auto simpleItem = static_cast<SimpleItem*>(index.internalPointer());
    if (!simpleItem) {
        return QVariant();
    }

    if(role == NameRole) {
        return simpleItem->name();
    }
    //This is used for displaying in QML
    else if(role == DateRole) {
        return simpleItem->dateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
    // This is used for dsiplaying in QML too
    else if(role == TimeRole) {
        return simpleItem->dateTime().toString("hh:mm");
    }
    // This Role is only used for sorting
    else if(role == DateTimeRole) {
        return simpleItem->dateTime();
    }

    return QVariant();
}
```

And in my **ProxyModel** that inherits from **QSortFilterProxyModel** class I have implemented `lessThan()` methood but it never gets called:

```
bool ProxyModel::lessThan(const QModelIndex &source_left, const QModelIndex &source_right) const
{
    qDebug() << "called lessThan()";
    QVariant leftData = sourceModel()->data(source_left);
    QVariant rightData = sourceModel()->data(source_right);

    if (leftData.userType() == QMetaType::QDateTime)
            return leftData.toDateTime() < rightData.toDateTime();

    return false;
}
```

What I am doing wrong or do you have any idea that I can try? If you need more code I will update.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Please provide a [mre] 2. Have you invoked the sort method?

Comment: @eyllanesc thank you so much, it works after calling `proxyModel.sort(0, Qt::DescendingOrder);` after `setSortRole`, Can you post it as answer so I can mark it?

Comment: The custom ProxyModel is useless. A plain QSortFilterProxyModel is doing the same.

Comment: @chehrlic in the example yes, but I am handling clicks on the items of the model so I need implementation of itemAt() method that will map the clicked item from the source model.

Comment: Still nothing what a normal QSortFilterProxyModel can not do - still no need for a custom one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you say

> it works after calling proxyModel.sort(0, Qt::DescendingOrder); after setSortRole